# Istgame package: how to get labels on both sides of a single edge?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, istgame

In the colored game tree below, there are edges that have labels on both sides. The label on one side of the edge is the probability of the action that is denoted on the other side of the edge. In the figure I used TikZ automata package but when I try to do the same using the istgame packge, I fail to get the label placement correct. The code illustrates the problem with a simpler example. In the code, the crucial line is

> \istb{v=20}[al] {(\frac{1}{4})}[br] \istb{v=4}[ar]{(\frac{3}{4})}[bl] As you can see in the black and white image, the probabilities are not displayed in the other side of the edge.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{istgame}
\begin{document}
\begin{istgame}
\xtdistance{25mm}{100mm}
\istroot(0){Nature}
  \istb{v=20}[al] {(\frac{1}{4})}[br] \istb{v=4}[ar]{(\frac{3}{4})}[bl] \endist
\xtdistance{25mm}{50mm}
\istroot(1)(0-1)<180>{}
  \istb{E}[al]  \istb{N}[ar]  \endist
\istroot(2)(0-2)<0>{}
  \istb{E}[al]  \istb{N}[ar]  \endist
\xtdistance{25mm}{25mm}
\istroot(3)(1-1)<180>{}
  \istb{E}[al]{\tiny{17.5,17.5}}  \istb{N}[ar]{\tiny{15,20}}  \endist
\istroot(4)(1-2)<180>{}
  \istb{E}[al]{\tiny{20,15}}  \istb{N}[ar]{\tiny{0,0}}  \endist
\istroot(5)(2-1)<0>{}
  \istb{E}[al]{\tiny{1.5,1.5}}  \istb{N}[ar]{\tiny{-1,4}}  \endist
\istroot(6)(2-2)<0>{}
  \istb{E}[al]{\tiny{4,-1}}  \istb{N}[ar]{\tiny{0,0}}  \endist
  \xtInfoset(3)(4){P2}
  \xtInfoset(5)(6){P2}
  \xtInfoset(1)(2){P1}
\end{istgame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think you need to use the `\istB` command instead of `\istb`. It takes two labels: `\istB{v=20}[al]{(\frac{1}{4})}[br] \istB{v=4}[ar]{(\frac{3}{4})}[bl]`. Does this produce the output you want?

Comment: @AlanMunn: Yes! Thank you so much! Please copy and paste your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you're looking for is `\istB` instead of `\istb`. The `\istB` command takes two labels so to add them you can use:

```
\istB{v=20}[al]{(\frac{1}{4})}[br] \istB{v=4}[ar]{(\frac{3}{4})}[bl]
```

Here's your complete example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{istgame}
\begin{document}
\begin{istgame}
\xtdistance{25mm}{100mm}
\istroot(0){Nature}
  \istB{v=20}[al]{(\frac{1}{4})}[br] \istB{v=4}[ar]{(\frac{3}{4})}[bl] \endist
\xtdistance{25mm}{50mm}
\istroot(1)(0-1)<180>{}
  \istb{E}[al]  \istb{N}[ar]  \endist
\istroot(2)(0-2)<0>{}
  \istb{E}[al]  \istb{N}[ar]  \endist
\xtdistance{25mm}{25mm}
\istroot(3)(1-1)<180>{}
  \istb{E}[al]{\tiny{17.5,17.5}}  \istb{N}[ar]{\tiny{15,20}}  \endist
\istroot(4)(1-2)<180>{}
  \istb{E}[al]{\tiny{20,15}}  \istb{N}[ar]{\tiny{0,0}}  \endist
\istroot(5)(2-1)<0>{}
  \istb{E}[al]{\tiny{1.5,1.5}}  \istb{N}[ar]{\tiny{-1,4}}  \endist
\istroot(6)(2-2)<0>{}
  \istb{E}[al]{\tiny{4,-1}}  \istb{N}[ar]{\tiny{0,0}}  \endist
  \xtInfoset(3)(4){P2}
  \xtInfoset(5)(6){P2}
  \xtInfoset(1)(2){P1}
\end{istgame}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]